# How to make only placeholder italics in input

Tags: html, input, placeholder

How can I format the text of a placeholder in italics, but when someone writes inside the textbox, the text shouldn't be in italics.

code:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search" style="font-style:italic">
```

How can I place italic text only on placeholder but not whole input?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Sure.  Just apply the style to these CSS rules:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;  
}
::-moz-placeholder {
   font-style: italic;  
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   font-style: italic; 
}
```

Probably not all of these rules are needed.  I always just reference [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/) because I always forget how to do it.

**Edit:** Note that these rules cannot be combined into one selector.  They must be declared separately as noted by [Dave Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015595/dave-kennedy) in the comments below.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that these rules have to be declared separately, i.e. `::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-moz-placeholder { font-style: italic; }` doesn't work.

Comment: @DaveKennedy Yes, you are correct.  I noticed that too.  I'm not sure why that is the case, however.

Comment: @DaveKennedy @JosephMarikle 
It's part of the [CSS3 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#Conformance). Specifically: _a group of selectors containing an invalid selector is invalid_. Therefore, because Firefox sees `:-ms-input-placeholder` as invalid, it makes the whole selector group as invalid. That's why you need to keep them separate.

Answer (score 38):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown), you can use the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class.

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
   font-style: italic;
}
```

This has the advantage of being un-prefixed, and the browser support is decent (92-ish%) at the time of this writing: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown.

Answer (score 4):

Another way: the :focus selector is your friend. To make it only for the placeholder use the :not selector. This have the CSS rule only if the input field is NOT current selection.
Define in your CSS :

```
.class-of-your-input-field:not(:focus) {
font-style:italic;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also make regular input text italic in addition to making placeholder text italic?

Comment: This has the unfortunate effect that once the empty input box gets focus, it will lose the italic, while still having the placeholder.